# VScode unittest test discovery settings for django app

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, visual-studio-code, python-unittest

I have a django app with some unittests. I want to run\debug them in VScode v.1.59.1.

My ./vscode/settings.json looks like this:

```
{
    "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
        "-v",
        "-s",
        "./routes/tests",
        "-p",
        "test*.py"
    ],
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true,
}
```

When I try to run\discover tests I have this output:

```
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_utils
...
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting REST_FRAMEWORK, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

When I try to run tests in regular django way with command:

```
python manage.py test
```

the tests working fine.

Please help me setup my VScode to run django unittests.

P.S: I can not install pytest, this should be done without installation of any new modules.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this too. It also causes the debug panel to not discover any tests at all.

Unlike when you run with ./manage.py test vscode has not initialized your app when starting the tests.

So; what I do is load settings and do setup() and then load the rest:

```py
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings.testing")

from django import setup

setup()

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
<other imports>

<your tests>
```